# how to search flickr photos using tag

Tags: api, flickr

There is way to search flickr photos using tag. Just open this [link](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.search), fill in the tag that you wants. You'll get the result ant its associated url link.

What if I want to write program to do the search? Actually I found a way. But it's kind of cheating. Through analyzing the return url link, for example:

http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&sort=random&method=flickr.photos.search&tags=girl&tag_mode=all&api_key=0e2b6aaf8a6901c264acb91f151a3350&nojsoncallback=1

It seems that I only need to replace the `tags=girl` with my need, saying `tags=dog`. It will work.

But still, I'd like to have a regular way to do this job. And What's the `api_key`? It seems it has nothing to do with the search result. For example:

http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=87700a0c78f2b7f2c167dd3e29ca141d&tags=dog&format=json&nojsoncallback=1

http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&sort=random&method=flickr.photos.search&tags=dog&tag_mode=all&api_key=0e2b6aaf8a6901c264acb91f151a3350&nojsoncallback=1

I use the above two different `api_key`s to search dog. It gives me the same result.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the [programming language](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/) you are using. For example, in C# it is as simple as:

```
var flickr = new Flickr("API_KEY", "SECRET");
var options = new PhotoSearchOptions();
options.TagMode = TagMode.AnyTag;
options.Tag = 'paris'; //The list of tags "comma separated"
options.Extras |= PhotoSearchExtras.DateTaken | PhotoSearchExtras.MediumUrl | PhotoSearchExtras.Tags;

PhotoCollection photos = flickr.PhotosSearch(options);
//In photos you will have the first 100 images.
```

But first you need an `API_KEY` to start using the API (it is a kind of authentication method to allow you to download data from Flickr).